# Running CLion on the System console (like Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, console, console-application, clion

I am trying to run a simple C++ program on CLion. The problem is that when I try to compile and run it, it shows the result in the application console. I want to run on the System console like the Visual Studio runs the output of the console apps. Is there a way of doing this. I use MINGW compiler.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an external terminal, do these steps.

1. (top menu) run\ edit Configurations
2. tick 'run in external console'

[image]

Comment: What IDE version is it? I don't have that option.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if anyone is still around wanting to open an external cmd window on run, there is a way to do it on Windows as well:

1. Go to Run > Edit Configurations
2. For the executable select C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
3. For program arguments use: /c "start cmd.exe @cmd /k "ProjectName.exe""
4. For working directory set the cmake debug (or release) folder
5. Save and select the profile from the dropdown right next to the run button

*Note: In the third step /k can be replaced with /c to make the window close after the program is run (with /c its more like visual studio and with /k its more like code blocks)*

Answer (score 1):

the above answer works fine in windows also. In working directory you can set this $CMakeCurrentBuildDir$
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPezZ.png)

Comment: Please don't put text in images.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Windows but in linux you can do it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675012/how-to-execute-a-clion-program-in-gnome-terminal/43440347#43440347).

You might be able to change the gnome-terminal to cmd if you are using windows but you will probably need to change the "Program Arguments" too.