# Viewing cout Output From CLion C++ file

Tags: c++11, clion

I recently downloaded CLion to use with C++ and it's working fine, I just wanted to know if/how I could view `std::cout`. If not in the CLion output console, then maybe in a separate terminal window using the CMakeLists.txt file? Again, my code is building fine, I just want to know how/if I can view the output (similar to what I'd be able to do in Eclipse, XCode, or even Sublime).

Comment: For linux system you can do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675012/how-to-execute-a-clion-program-in-gnome-terminal/43440347#43440347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see it in the "run" tab, not the "terminal" tab

[image]

From the dropdown box at the top, make sure you have the correct target selected and hit the play button.