# I want to use run my CLion programs in a Terminal window

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, clion

Is there any way I can execute my programs in Terminal window on CLion on Mac like with say Visual Studio on Windows?

Comment: There's [this way of doing it for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440347/1270789) so I presume it would be quite similar for the Mac, just substitute whatever the Mac terminal is called.

Comment: BTW, my research suggests that the "Executable" should point to `/usr/bin/open`.

Comment: I just tried and there's no open file in that directory or path. There is /usr/bin but not open. May it's called something else or I might be wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a CLion program in gnome terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675012/how-to-execute-a-clion-program-in-gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. Why can't you simply:

- open a terminal window
- change the directory to the folder where CLion outputs the .exe file
- run the .exe

That should be the general OS-agnostic process.

What part of it is stumping you on a Mac? We all want to help but you may have to give us more info before we can understand what you really need to know.

Comment: I need step by step guide how to change directory. And I don’t know where is .exe file located. I’m actually new this stuff.