# LInk Curses in Mac OS CMake

Tags: clion, curses

I want to make my CLion compatible with curses library for C.
Here's my sample application

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ncurses.h"

int main() {
    initscr();
    printw("Hello world");
    refresh();

    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(untitled main.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ncurses)
```

But when I run the application, I get into this error

`Error opening terminal: unknown.`

Comment: your `TERM` environment variable is not set

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675012/how-to-execute-a-clion-program-in-gnome-terminal/43440347#43440347

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit your CMakeLists.txt file to be as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_compile_options(-g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)

set(INCLUDE_DIR include)
include_directories (${INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

Just tested it now, and it works fine in Clion latest version ( mine at the time of writing this answer is v2020.3)

Mind you, it's not possible to debug the lib commands, but you can compile and run in the console-terminal (i.e. don't run it from the "terminal" that is inside CLion, use the system one instead), this is because the code is designed to run in a text-type terminal whilst the one inside of CLion is a Graphical one.

I hope this helps

Good luck,

H